# Performing a SQL query to get cocktails by ingredient ID on many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I need help creating a SQL query that will return a cocktail from a database, given that I have supplied all the ingredients that go into that cocktail

So for example, I want the "Gin and Tonic" row to return only if I have supplied the correct ids for Gin (id is 1) and Tonic (id is 2). I I only supply "Tonic," I shouldn't get back the row

I'm using SQLAlchemy and Flask, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around how the query will work altogether

This is what my table structure looks like

```
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_my_database |
+-------------------+
| cocktails         |
| ing_in_cocktails  |
| ingredients       |
+-------------------+
```

This is my cocktails table

```
+----+----------------+-------+---------+
| id | name           | glass | finish  |
+----+----------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | white russisan | rocks | stirred |
|  2 | gin and tonic  | rocks | stirred |
+----+----------------+-------+---------+
```

This is my ingredients table

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | name    | ing_type |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | vodka   | fruit    |
|  2 | kahluha | fruit    |
|  3 | gin     | fruit    |
|  4 | tonic   | fruit    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

And this is my relational table

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | cocktail_id | ing_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |      1 |
|  2 |           1 |      2 |
|  3 |           2 |      3 |
|  4 |           2 |      4 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

Here are the corresponding SQLAlchemy models

```
class Cocktail(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cocktails'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    glass = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    finish = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    ingredients = db.relationship(
        'Ingredient',
        secondary=ing_in_cocktails,
        backref=db.backref('cocktails', lazy='dynamic')
    )

class Ingredient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredients'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    ing_type = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)


ing_in_cocktails = db.Table(
    'ing_in_cocktails',
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('cocktail_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cocktails.id')),
    db.Column('ing_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ingredients.id'))
)
```

This query got me most of the way there, but the issue here is that it's returning "Gin and Tonic" if I provide any of the ingredient in the cocktail

```
# problematic because this returns "Gin and Tonic," despite not passing
# all the ingredients
Cocktail.query.join(ing_in_cocktails).filter(ing_in_cocktails.columns.ing_id.in_([3]))
```

and the query above translates to this SQL

```
SELECT cocktails.id AS cocktails_id, cocktails.name AS cocktails_name, cocktails.glass AS cocktails_glass, cocktails.finish AS cocktails_finish
FROM cocktails INNER JOIN ing_in_cocktails ON cocktails.id = ing_in_cocktails.cocktail_id
WHERE ing_in_cocktails.ing_id IN (%(ing_id_1)s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a list of cocktails for which do not have any missing ingredients, that is there does `NOT EXIST` any missing ingredients.  Missing ingredients are those that are `NOT IN` your list of available ingredients.  With those observations in place a query that satisfies your requirement can be written like this:

```
select c.* from Cocktails c
 where not exists (select 1 from ing_in_cocktails r
                    where r.cocktail_id = c.id
                      and r.ing_id not in (3,4));
```

If the supplied list of ingredients is 3, 4 then you can make your desired Gin and Tonic, if either ingredient 3 or 4 is missing from the supplied list, then you can't.

Comment: Thanks I ended up going with this and was able to translate into SQLAlchemy after some trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the SQLAlchemy to do this

```
      query = db.session.query(Cocktail).filter(
          ~exists().where(
              and_(
                  CocktailIngredient.cocktail_id == Cocktail.id,
                  ~CocktailIngredient.ing_id.in_([15, 17])
              )
          )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you, how to write it in python, but here is sql, that you need, I hope, it will help

```
select
     ic.cocktail_id
from ing_in_cocktails ic
left join (
    -- here are you ingredients, that you have to pass as parameters.
    -- keep in mind, that they must be unique
    select 1 as ing_id
    union all select 2
    union all select 4
) ing_p on ic.ing_id = ing_p.ing_id
group by ic.cocktail_id
having count(*) = count(ing_p.ing_id) -- just need to check here, that amount of ingredients in cocktail is equal to ingredients, you passed as parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following query with correlated subquery in `HAVING` clause

```
select c.id
from cocktails c
join ing_in_cocktails ic on c.id = ic.cocktail_id 
where ing_id IN (1, 2)
group by c.id
having count(*) = (
  select count(*)
  from ing_in_cocktails
  where cocktail_id = c.id
)
```